# Can't apply KB3165756 to Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a licensed version of Microsoft's Visual Studio 2015 Professional operating on Windows 10 Enterprise. The Help/About displays this, in part:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Professional
```

Visual Studio has been pestering me to apply KB3165756 for more than a week, so as to update things from 14.0.25424.0 to 14.0.25425.01. I select the link and it downloads vs14-kb3165756.exe to my computer. I start this program and run it. After a short delay (and getting through a few security prompts), the program aborts with this display:

[image]

I click on the link to examine the log file (the common issues and workarounds link is completely worthless so far as I'm able to see) and I get quite a long laundry list of errors near the bottom. This is the [error log file](http://www.infinitefactors.org/misc/dd_patch_KB3165756_20160811152242.log) I get.

I have re-tried this any number of times, including completely shutting down the computer and rebooting and then re-trying the operation. It always fails at the same point. It also always adds the point about "user cancelled installation." But I didn't actually participate. All I did was watch the installation process acquire some files and then fail. Perhaps just a few minutes' time to get there.

(I do have a few add-ons in Visual Studio 2015. I can provide a complete list, if that is needed. Or I can check an item if someone feels it's important to check for particular ones. Most of them are from Microsoft, though. And no, I have not removed them all and tried to go back to the beginning installation process and then re-apply everything in some different order.)

I'd appreciate any productive thoughts about how to get this patch applied. I'm getting to the point of considering a complete uninstall of Visual Studio, a re-install from the original DVD, and then re-application of patches. (But, of course, I'd like to avoid that.)

Answer (score 4):

Even I faced the same issue, which looks like a problem with the online installer of this KB update. I could resolve it by making an offline installer and installing it using the following steps:

1. Download the installer of the KB3165756 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx. It is an online installer (A minimal installer **VS14-KB3165756.exe** of 2.45 MB, which will download the content on the go from internet).
2. Open a command prompt and point to the location where VS14-KB3165756.exe is located.
3. Run the command `VS14-KB3165756.exe /layout`. It will start a Visual Studio Setup Window asking for the download location where you want to download this.
   Select and location as the file location of VS14-KB3165756.exe. For example if your VS14-KB3165756.exe is in `C:\VS14-KB3165756.exe` then select the download location as `C:\packages` and it will download there.
4. Now, keep your system network disconnected and try to install the VS14-KB3165756.exe and it will take the offline package and install successfully instead of trying to download. For example, if you are running VS14-KB3165756.exe from `C:\VS14-KB3165756.exe`, then it will look for packages files from `C:\packages`.

Comment: I have since completely scrubbed the O/S and re-installed 2015 from scratch. That's worked just fine. I wish I'd been able to try out your suggestion here, as it seems to be a lot less work than what I did to resolve it. It's too late now for me to test your suggestion. But perhaps someone else will try this out and let us know how it works for them. Thanks for adding this. I think I've learned something useful, regardless. I just wish I could personally validate it, now. I'll up your answer, since I think there are some useful bits to know here, regardless.

Comment: I would scrub win10 and go back to the best OS, for security professionals,  Win7 if you have experience.  ( Same opinion for Steve Gibson... @grc.com  too much Win X telemetry scheduled tasks and background sniffing by MS and bloatware.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as described with /layout switch, then blocked all internet traffic but nothing changes, the error messages is: 
KB3165756 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

This is sligthly different to the problem above. Finally, i succeeded with this answer:

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3165756) Setup Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213152/visual-studio-2015-update-3-kb3165756-setup-blocked)

If the solution above does not help, maybe try it that way (main difference: after local download via VS14-KB3165756.exe /layout , in Step 4: use also commandline to install with VS14-KB3165756.exe /uninstall to install (sounds paradox), then click [repair] button in upcoming window. Works great!