# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3165756) Setup Blocked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-10, updates

So, I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on my new Windows 10 laptop, but I can't get it to install to save my life. When I tried installing it via the original installation ISO, it keeps telling me the package failed. If I use the standalone update file it tells me the setup is blocked and that it requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present (which, by all rights, should already be installed).

Here's a link to the log file, if it helps...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXn28otvziTdGRwamVjaTZ2RlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think, this post should be posted in SuperUser community. If wrong, do correct me.

Comment: Perhaps, but I saw several other questions about similar problems to mine in the Stack Overflow community, so I just posted it here, since Visual Studio installation is kind of related to programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out how to fix it.

1. Shift-right click on the folder where the standalone update is stored.
2. Click "Open command window here."
3. Type "vs14-kb3165756.exe /uninstall" without the quotes.
4. Click "repair."
5. Watch as the update finally manages to work.

Comment: since you already found the workaround, could you mark it as answer? So other community members who have the same or similar issue can easier search your solution.

Comment: Sorry I didn't do it sooner. I tried to do it the same day I found the answer, but it told me I had to wait a day for some reason. I ended up forgetting about it until now.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing TheDoctor's answer, what worked for me was:

1. I had to "open the file location" of CMD
2. Create shortcut of it on my Desktop and "Run as Administrator"
3. Found the path where the vs14-kb3165756.exe was saved 
   [(in my case was in Downloads folder)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/claSi.jpg)
4. Typed vs14-kb3165756.exe /uninstall
5. Clicked "repair"
6. And then miraculously the thing works! Thanks TheDoctor for the solution!